# How to call Google Assistant API from the Dialogflow webhook?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

In webhooks from Dialogflow, is there a way to trigger Google Assistant APIs, get back the result and display in Dialogflow?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. The Assistant API currently only takes voice input, and there is no way to get the user's voice in Dialogflow. In theory, you could run it through a TTS, feed that to the API, get the response back, and feed that through STT, but that seems like a pain.

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make my bot answering few specific questions, and for all other questions I want to get answers from Google Assistant. That my my bot will be much more intelligent in common sense.

Answer (score 1):

Google Assistant webhook will not make your bot more intelligent. You need to create right intents in your Dialogflow Agent to make it intelligent enough to do Natural Language Processing and trigger the right intent. Whatever webhook you create (Google Assistant or other) they will just work as you have coded.

In short, Dialogflow is doing the NLP stuff and making your bot intelligent and webhook will do tasks based on the identified intent or action.

To integrate GA with Dialogflow, best way would be to use [NodeJS client](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) for Action-on-Google and add it to your webhook project like `require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp`

Follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app) and understand how to create a GA webhook for Dialogflow.

It would be better if you can explain exactly what you want to do. That way, the community members can answer your question in a better way.